# scald.rb results in error (could not find or load main class)

Tags: ruby, scala, sbt, scalding

I am trying to run the tutorial files from https://github.com/twitter/scalding/tree/develop/tutorial.
I cloned the 0.17.x branch and current develop branch and haven't had much success with either.

I have also already ran "sbt update" and "sbt assembly" to create the fat jar which is used by this scald.rb script.

Upon running the command below from the root scalding directory

```
scripts/scald.rb --local tutorial/Tutorial0.scala
```

I receive either of these errors:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files
[SUGGESTION]: Try scald.rb --clean, you may have corrupt jars lying around
```

or

```
Error: Could not find or load main class scala.tools.nsc.Main
[SUGGESTION]: Try scald.rb --clean, you may have corrupt jars lying around
```

Whatever I try to do I cannot get the scald.rb script to work. I have tried the clean option and many other stackoverflow answers such as setting scala_home in my environment variables and path to scala/bin. Many versions of sbt/scala and nothing works.

#### Current Software:

-Ruby 2.4.2-2-x86

-sbt 0.13.15

-Scala 2.11.8

-scalding 0.17.x branch